# Wildfly 10 with Postgres 9.6.6 and Hibernate 5.2.12.final

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, wildfly

I am trying to get a Java8EE application working on Wildfly10 and Postgres 9.6.6.

Somehow I allways bump into the error that the relation cannot be found.

My Postgres is running on localhost, default port. I am connecting with the user postgres and the correct password. The database (hbnac) has a schema with the same name.

Wildfly is configured to use the database and the “Test connection” is confirming a successful connection.
Using pgAdmin 4 I can also browse the database, see the schema, as well as the table group_member.

The config in Jboss looks as follow:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/hbnac" pool-name="hbnac" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hbnac</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgres</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <initial-pool-size>1</initial-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                    <flush-strategy>Gracefully</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

However, my application fails to select a record from the very same table, resulting in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "group_member" does not exist
```

The configuration of my persistence.xml is doing a jndi lookup of the connection defined in Wildfly:

```
<persistence-unit name="hbnac">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/hbnac</jta-data-source>

    <class>hbnac.birthday.domain.groupmember.GroupMember</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect" />
        <!--property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/-->
        <!--property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="hbnac"/-->

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

And obviously, the jta-data-source is matching the working datasource in Wildfly. As you can see, I have experimented a bit with the validate (which fails for the same reason at startup) and with the schema name, which also does not make a difference.

The entity itsel is annoted:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_member")
public class GroupMember extends AbstractEntity {

public final static String FACEBOOK_NAME_FIELD = "facebookName";
public final static String BIRTHDAY_FIELD = "birthday";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
```

It has getters, setters, hashcode and equals methode for all fields available.

If I copy the query generated by hibernate into pgadmin it also works perfectly...

Any ideas left?

[image: A screenshot from the actual db in pgadmin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error after many tries! It was caused by the configuration of the Postgres module in Wildfly itself.

What I had before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgres">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.1.4.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true" />
    </dependencies>
```

and in the standalone.xml:

```
<driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

for the datasource itself:

```
 <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/hbnac" pool-name="hbnac" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hbnac</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>postgres</driver>
                ...
```

This configuration gave a successful connection but the error that a relation could not be found.

By replacing it with the following configuration, everything is working fine:

For the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgres">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-42.1.4.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

For the driver in the standalone.xml:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgres">
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

And finally for the db connection:

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/PostgresDS" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hbnac</connection-url>
     <driver>postgresql</driver>
     <security>
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

success to test connection, but even couldn't find table
that indicates ,perhaps schema setting is not defined correctly.
then, should put a currentSchema like this

```
<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hbnac?currentSchema=hbnac</connection-url>
```

and if you use Hibernate to issue query should enable this comment outed code

```
<!--property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="hbnac"/-->
```

Comment: I have tried these settings, also changing the search path at a database level (ALTER DATABASE hbnac SET search_path TO hbnac;), but nothing helps...

I am really thinking that I am the victim of some kind of bug ...